# auto refresh results div when running SQL Queries in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this JS/Ajax code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready (function () {
    var updater = setTimeout (function () {
        $('div#ContentLeft').load('live_stats1.php', 'update=true')
    $('div#ContentRight').load('live_stats2.php', 'update=true')
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

which refreshes the content divs but they are not refreshing correctly.

My HTML is:

```
<div id="ContentLeft">
<?php include 'live_stats1.php'; ?>
</div>

<div id="ContentLeft">
<?php include 'live_stats2.php'; ?>
</div>
```

then on `live_stats1.php` and `live_stats2.php` i have my queries only

the queries take a while to run, so the results disappear until the queries have run again. how can i make it so the results stay in the divs until the new results have loaded?

and also if i check the console in google chrome, the local resources a new `jquery.min.js` file is added every time it refreshes

here is a [link](http://pastebin.com/qAmvbZ0Z) to what my full PHP code looks like.

i want to be able to refresh the result divs only periodically

Comment: i have posted my answer please check it and let me know

Comment: check my comment and my edit

Comment: I've updated my answer check it now and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this

JS :

```
$(document).ready (function () {



    function updatedivs(responsediv,linkurl)
    {

        $.post(linkurl,function(response){
             $(responsediv).html(response);
        });
    }

    var updater = setTimeout (function () {

          var preventcache =  (new Date).getTime();

          updatedivs($('div#ContentLeft'),'live_stats1.php?update=true&r='+preventcache);
          updatedivs($('div#ContentRight'),'live_stats2.php?update=true&r='+preventcache);

    }, 1000);

});
```

Html :

```
<div id="ContentLeft">
<?php include 'live_stats1.php'; ?>
</div>

<div id="ContentRight">
<?php include 'live_stats2.php'; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: it still seems to be duplicating the divs, check my edit

Comment: for some reason, it shows the correct results for live_stats1.php then on refresh it sets them all two zero except for the first query

Comment: you are using 2 `divs` ids in your answer as same id name `ContentLeft` there is no `ContentRight` rename the second one to `ContentRight` and try again

Comment: i know, already done that. and ignore my last comment. its now only updating on page load and not every X seconds

Comment: try now its should work , the problem is `jquery` sometime cache the request so I've added `timestamp` to the link to prevent `jquery` cache

Comment: its still not automatically refreshing

Comment: check the chrome `javascript` `console` is there any errors ?

Answer (score 0):

Delete `<?php include 'live_stats1.php'; ?>` and `<?php include 'live_stats2.php'; ?>` since you will get your stats anyways. Also, try to use caching if you have heavy select queries.

Comment: still duplicating the divs

Comment: it looks like: http://postimg.org/image/6l31dj3md/ whereas there should just be one div for each

Comment: Damn, you have 2x `id="ContentLeft"` in your html :)

Comment: i realised that too :) have already changed it but still same issues